# Kabylake without BIOS update

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, build, kaby-lake

I am going to build my first PC soon and I need to know will the MSI z270 A pro mother board work with a i3 7100k
Without bios update.   - thanks

Comment: Check the CPU compatibility list.  It provides what CPUs each revision of the firmware.  Unlike memory compatibility lists, the CPU list, should be trusted

Comment: I don't see any mention of BIOS versions in the CPU support list ( https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z270-A-PRO.html#support-cpu )

Comment: That means it's unlikely your CPU is supported by revision 12 nor 10 (which is the stock release firmware).  I wouldn't risk a purchase like that without knowing without a doubt it would work, and even if it does support it, a firmware update would be required for that to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly yes.

That motherboard has a "200 series" chipset which was released at the same time as the kaby-lake processors. So you shouldn't have to worry about getting an old-stock board with an outdated bios.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not certain about that specific motherboard, but I know that motherboards which need firmware updates to support the new CPU won't be usable until an old CPU is used to update the firmware.  That is to say, unless you have a spare old CPU, it won't work.  A better choice is to buy a newer motherboard that explicitly supports the new CPU out of the box.

Comment: This is a motherboard with the latest chipset released at the same time as the kaby-lake processors, so it's almost certainly ok. I wish the motherboard vendors would do a better job of communicating what processors were gauranteed to work out of the box verses which may need a BIOS update though.

Comment: @plugwash They actually do. They tell you specifically what firmware revisions supports which CPUs.  If the retailers don't indicate that information that's on them.

Comment: Careful, "almost certainly OK" is a dangerous assumption, especially for a first-time build.  If you had an older machine with some older parts to swap in, I'd say go for it.  But please, contact the vendor for confirmation.  Don't expect to be able to blame one of us volunteers if it goes poorly.  The vendor is the source of truth.